# Access levels in C#

Tags: c#, c++, access-levels

Quick simple questions,

Is there any way to declare the access level of more then one variable or method in C# as in C++?

Aswell, is it the same in C# as in C++ where the members of a `struct` are, if not defined, `public` and the members of a `class` are `private`?

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) No: Each variable is declared separately and may be qualified with a member access modifier. Exceptions are variables of the same type which can share a type and member access modifier.

2.) No: The same rules as for classes apply - by default members are `private` if no access modifier is specified, big difference is that `struct` is a value type and not a reference type.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't do that in general, unless the variables are of the same type as in

```
public int a,b,c;
```

Comment: So a follow question, when I was taught C++ declaring variables in one line was considered bad code standard. How is it in the world of C#?

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can declare multiple variables on a single line as such:

```
<access> <type> <name> [= <default>] [, <name> [= <default>]...]
```

so

```
private int a = 1, b, c=3;
```

Structs are not often used bit of the access modifier is not declared, it is private for structs and classes alike.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't declare an access type, it will be as private as it can be. The default for non-nested types is internal, and for nested types is private.

Comment: OP is referring to members not types the default is private for members